# Badges for tourists achievements/quests

Tags: outdoor-games

In Poland [Polish Tourist and Sightseeing Society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PTTK) (PTTK), has created set of badges that can be awarded to tourists for various achievements in different activities (hiking, skiing, kayaking, etc).

These are physical badges (pins) that are awarded to person only after submitting logbook proving that they met the conditions. [Photos](https://www.google.com/search?q=odznaki%20pttk&tbm=isch).

I was wondering if there are any other organizations worldwide having similar system of badges/pins/patches awarded to tourists for some achievements/quests.

Comment: I think this is in scope. Also made it CW, so people can contribute easily and it's really wiki style question. Also was not sure about what tags to use here.

Comment: Hi pbm! For people that may be new to our system, I just want to quickly explain what CW is, especially before more answers start popping up!

Comment: CW stands for Community Wiki, which is a single answer to the question, and should be edited instead of adding new answers. It has no rep and everyone can contribute. From the Help Center: CWs "have been donated to the community in hopes that others will edit them to keep them up to date, to add useful information, and generally improve their quality."  They're most useful with questions that might be off topic as "lists" or that  "might become obsolete." [This page](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) in the [Help] explains it best!

Comment: The US National Park Service has a popular passport program where you collect stamps for visiting parks. There is no activity requirement though. The FAI awards badges for various aviation feats, which doesn't require tourism though it's natural to travel somewhere scenic when earning them.

Comment: Just as an aside, CW is now generally deprecated, or at least not encouraged, across SE, as "lists" and "offtopic" are more strictly observed.

Comment: If pilgrimages count, then this has been around a very long time.  Some pilgrims probably don't like to be referred to as tourists, though.

Comment: @Roger: what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @pbm wikipedia's entry on "pilgrim badge" pretty much covers it:  "Pilgrim badges are decorations worn by some of those who undertake a Christian pilgrimage to a place considered holy by the Church. They became very popular among Catholics in the later medieval period. Typically made of lead alloy, they were sold as souvenirs at sites of Christian pilgrimage and bear imagery relating to the saint venerated there. The production of pilgrim badges flourished in the Middle Ages in Europe, particularly in the 14th and 15th centuries"  I can turn this into an answer if you like.

Comment: @Roger: I'd say that pilgrim badges are way different as they're more like souvenirs that anyone can buy and there are no requirements you have to met to wear one.

Answer (score 7):

## North America

### USA

#### Eastern USA

- [Appalachian Mountain Club (AMC) Four Thousand Footer Club](http://www.amc4000footer.org/) has a [set of challenges](http://www.amc4000footer.org/the-lists-we-recognize.html) where after climbing top peaks of NH/NE you can receive a patch.
- [NH Division of Forests & Lands](https://www.nh.gov/nhdfl/index.htm) - after visiting some of their fire lookout towers you can [receive a patch](https://www.nh.gov/nhdfl/natural-heritage/fire-towers/index.htm).
- [The White Mountains 4000 Footer Grid](http://48x12.com/) is a set of challenges to hike top peaks of NH in each month of the year.
- [ADK 46ers](http://www.adk46er.org/) are the hikers who complete the 46 4000' summits in the Adirondack mountains of northern New-York. There is also a separate badge for those who complete the list only during official winter (solstice to solstice).

### Canada

#### Québec

- [Rando Québec - certificat du randonneur émérite](https://www.randoquebec.ca/certificat-du-randonneur-emerite/) - This is a list of 75 hiking trails, not necessarily reaching summits, that grants 3 badges, one for every 25 trail a hiker finishes: bronze, silver, and gold.

## Europe

### Poland

- [Polish Tourist and Sightseeing Society](http://www.amc4000footer.org/) (PTTK) has massive set of pins (possibly hundreds) for various achievements. For example:

  - [Górska Odznaka Turystyczna (Mountain Tourist Badge) (pl)](http://www.amc4000footer.org/the-lists-we-recognize.html) - with few different levels awarded for hiking X numbers of kilometers in Polish mountains
  - [Szlak Wisły (pl)](https://www.nh.gov/nhdfl/index.htm) (Vistula Trail) - for kayaking (or sailing) whole length of [Vistula](https://www.nh.gov/nhdfl/natural-heritage/fire-towers/index.htm) river
  - bunch of local badges for summiting top X peaks in different mountains in the country
  - many more - there are multiple branches of PTTK each creating their own badges for their local area. List (not extensive) can be found [here (pl)](http://www.msw-pttk.org.pl/odznaki/o_odznakach/ok.html) and [here (pl)](http://www.msw-pttk.org.pl/odznaki/o_odznakach/otk.html).
- [Polskie Towarzystwo Tatrzańskie (pl)](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polskie_Towarzystwo_Tatrza%C5%84skie) (Polish Tatra Mountains Society) has a similar system, but focusing on mountain hiking achievements. [Some of the badges (pl)](http://www.ptt.org.pl/odznaki-turystyczne/) include badges for finishing various Polish long distance trails (100-500 km).

### UK

- [Dartmoor Letterboxing](https://letterboxingondartmoor.co.uk/?page_id=19) is mainly restricted to Dartmoor,  Devon.  It's something of a precursor to geocaching: boxes with stamps and visitor books are hidden - or kept behind the bar in pubs etc.  The 100 club issues patches for finding 100 (and multiples).
- Long-distance cyclists can join [Audax UK](https://www.audax.uk/shop/) and then buy patches for various achievements starting from 50 km rides, seeing the country as they do so.

### Austria

This concept is known in German as "Wandernadel" and implemented by a lot of local tourist assiciations, usually in the form of a "book" you can stamp at designated stamp stations on interesting locations.  Examples are [Vienna](https://www.wien.gv.at/umwelt/wald/freizeit/wandern/nadel.html), [Schladming](https://www.schladming-dachstein.at/de/schladming/wanderabenteuer/wanderpass), [Gastein](https://www.gasteiner-wanderbuch.at/wandernadel.html), but there are many more if you google the term.

(The same seems to be true in parts of Germany, there's at least a [Harzer Wandernadel](https://www.harzer-wandernadel.de/).)